# How can non-admins view which files are open on a file server?

Tags: windows, networking, permissions

I'm on a windows workstation, and I want a list of which files are open over the network on a windows server. The Shared Folders MMC Snap-in does this visually, and SysInternals' PSFile does it from the command line, but by default only for admins. I want to let regular users do this, too. What permissions do I need to grant them?

UPDATE: Running sysinternals' accesschk utility, I've found that there are lots of "weird" objects that have permissions but aren't in the filesystem, registry, or active directory. Run "accesschk -o" to see a list of object directories, and then add the name of a directory ("accesschk -o \BaseNamedObjects", for example) to see them. Could the functionality I'm looking for relate to some permissions in here? If so, is there any way to edit the ACLs on these things? (Even if not, I'd still love to find out which specific object represents the ability to enumerate remotely opened files.)

Comment: Just for my curiosity can you tell us why non admins need this ability?

Comment: If you find a way, be sure to report it to Microsoft so they can fix it!!

Comment: I've wanted this for a variety of reasons, currently because the users of our portfolio management software often need to know a) who else is using it right now, and b) which files they're editing, since this can affect reporting and bulk updates, among other things. I wrote a script that parses the output from PSFile to present this information neatly, but currently only I can run it.

Answer (score 1):

create a service that gets the info then dumps the result somewhere!

Comment: also it really is a strange request!

Comment: Yes, this would work, but it seems like an awfully awkward kludge. Anything an Admin can do can be done by any user with the right permissions set... right? There must be some file, registry entry, or other object on which I can grant read access to non-admins. I just can't figure out where.

Comment: yes you could subinacl your way to a solution but in this case the final result might be admin any way.